# Getting an error when running npm install plotly.js

Tags: plotly.js

It happens to versions 1.39.0 and above:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @etpinard/gl-text@^1.1.6

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/zvulun/.npm/_logs/2018-08-29T16_49_32_780Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Issue still exists.  Could it be a bug or perhaps they changed the package name?

Comment: Nevermind, I was following [this guide](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/realtime-charts-with-plot-ly/) and wrote `npm install plotly.ls --save` instead of `npm install plotly.js --save`